# Replacement battery in MacBook Pro 2009 doesn't charge

Tags: charge

I had a dead battery on my Mac so I bought a new one. Installed it and it works fine.

After the battery got low, I plugged in the charger but nothing happens, it just won't charge the battery. When the charger is plugged in it just flickers orange.

Any ideas?

**Update:** I guess the charging system is toast, but love my Mac and would like to get it fixed, reasonably priced.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Could you add the manufacturer and model of the replacement battery?

Comment: Does the charger led go green or orange?

Comment: Are you sure the previous battery was dead? Is it possible that something in the charging electronics is broken and not the battery itself is at fault here?

Comment: When the charger is plugged in it just flickers orange

Comment: Replacing the power unit is likely to be expensive. You would do much better to put money towards a new MBP (or even a secondhand newer one). You're already limited to El Capitan, so software compatibility is going to become a problem. You're already missing USB 3, Thunderbolt, HDMI, etc, etc.